# Does Redis implement the touch method?

Tags: express, session, redis

This is important to underdstand for configuration purposes.

If it does implement the touch method than I can safely set resave to `false`.

```
session({
  // blah blah
  resave: false
});
```

How would I go about looking into this as it is not readily available information on the docs page.

I did find this but I think it is a different touch()

https://redis.io/commands/touch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the redis connector for express-session implements `touch`.  If you look at the [relevant portion of the source](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/blob/master/lib/connect-redis.js#L61) for the [connect-redis module](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) (which is how redis supports express-session), you will find that it does implement the touch method unless an option is passed to disable it.

Here's the relevant source:

```
touch(sid, sess, cb = noop) {
  if (this.disableTouch) return cb()

  let key = this.prefix + sid
  this.client.expire(key, this._getTTL(sess), (err, ret) => {
    if (err) return cb(err)
    if (ret !== 1) return cb(null, 'EXPIRED')
    cb(null, 'OK')
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks jfriend!  how were you so quickly able to locate it in the source.  can you let me know so I can check on my own next time?

Comment: @j.a. - I googled "express session redis".  The third hit is a github link for tj/connect-redis.  I opened that, verified it was the module I was looking for, found the one main source file in lib/connect-redis.js.  I opened that file and searched for "touch" and found the method.  The beauty of open source is that the source is out there to find and analysis of that source can eventually answer any question you have.

Comment: thanks will the main file always be in the `lib` directory or how did you know to look in there.  Other projects are much bigger.